# flatten data in SQL based on fixed set of column

Tags: sql, view, google-bigquery, flatten

I am stuck with a specific scenario of flattening the data and need help for it. I need the output as flattened data where the column values are not fixed. Due to this I want to restrict the output to fixed set of columns.

Given Table 'test_table'

| ID | Name | Property |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 | xxx |
| 2 | C2 | xyz |
| 2 | C3 | zz |

The scenario is, column Name can have any no. of values corresponding to an ID. I need to flatten the data based in such a way that there is one row per ID field. Since the Name field varies with each ID, I want to flatten it for fix 3 columns like Co1, Co2, Co3. The output should look like

| ID | Co1 | Co1_Property | Co2 | Co2_Property | Co3 | Co3_Property |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 | xxx | null | null |  |  |
| 2 | C2 | xyz | C3 | zz |  |  |

Could not think of a solution using Pivot or aggregation. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `I want to flatten it for fix 3 columns ` - not clear! what if you have more than 3 (let's say 5) entries for particular ID? will you want 5 columns in output?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant as per the requirement, the field Name can go upto any value, so I want to restrict it to fix no. of columns for all the IDs. if say any ID has 5 values then 2/5 will be ignored in output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arrays:

```
select id,
       array_agg(name order by name)[safe_ordinal(1)] as name_1,
       array_agg(property order by name)[safe_ordinal(1)] as property_1,
       array_agg(name order by name)[safe_ordinal(2)] as name_2,
       array_agg(property order by name)[safe_ordinal(2)] as property_2,
       array_agg(name order by name)[safe_ordinal(3)] as name_3,
       array_agg(property order by name)[safe_ordinal(3)] as property_3
from t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

All current answers are too verbose and involve heavy repetition of same fragments of code again and again and if you need to account more columns you need to copy paste and add more lines which will make it even more verbose!
My preference is to avoid such type of coding and rather use something more generic as in below example

```
select * from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by id) col
  from `project.dataset.table`)
pivot (max(name) as name, max(property) as property for col in (1, 2, 3))
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

If you want to change number of output columns - you just simply modify `for col in (1, 2, 3)` part of query.
For example if you would wanted to have 5 columns - you would use `for col in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` - that simple!!!

Comment: have you tried? did it work for you? would be great to know :o)

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, this solution is good, but in my scenario, I had a special requirement to prefix all the columns like col1_name, col2_name which I am not able to perform using Pivot. Had it been possible by this then definitely this would have saved lot of extra code.

Answer (score 0):

The standard practice is to use conditional aggregation.  That is, to use `CASE` expressions to pick which row goes to which column, then `MAX()` to collapse multiple rows into individual rows...

```
SELECT
  id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'C1' THEN name     END)  AS co1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'C1' THEN property END)  AS co1_property,
  MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'C2' THEN name     END)  AS co2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'C2' THEN property END)  AS co2_property,
  MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'C3' THEN name     END)  AS co3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN name = 'C3' THEN property END)  AS co3_property
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  id
```

Background info:

- Not having an `ELSE` in the `CASE` expression implicitly means `ELSE NULL`
- The intention is therefore for each column to recieve `NULL` from every input row, except for the row being pivoted into that column
- Aggregates, such as `MAX()` essentially skip `NULL` values
- `MAX( {NULL,NULL,'xxx',NULL,NULL} )` therefore equals `'xxx'`

---

A similar approach "bunches" the values to the left *(so that `NULL` values always only appears to the right...)*

That approach first uses `row_number()` to give each row a value corresponding to which column you want to put that row in to..

```
WITH
  sorted AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY name)  AS seq_num
  FROM
    yourTable
)
SELECT
  id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN seq_num = 1 THEN name     END)  AS co1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN seq_num = 1 THEN property END)  AS co1_property,
  MAX(CASE WHEN seq_num = 2 THEN name     END)  AS co2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN seq_num = 2 THEN property END)  AS co2_property,
  MAX(CASE WHEN seq_num = 3 THEN name     END)  AS co3,
  MAX(CASE WHEN seq_num = 3 THEN property END)  AS co3_property
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  id
```